# tensorflow - Can I have entries in my input array that are tuples? Doing this throws 'Unable to get element from the feed as bytes.'

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, python-3.4

Ultimately my question is: Is it possible to have run tensorflow's DNNClassifier on samples in which one entry is a tuple or set of tuples?

What I want is to run a classifier on a bunch of samples.  Mostly the samples are numbers, but I also want one of the entries to be a set of numbers, e.g. a sample is <1, 2, 3, 4, (1.5, 1.6, 1.4), 2>.  I actually want the weird entry to be a set of tuples of potentially different sizes, like one sample is <1, 2, 3, 4, (1.5, 1.6, 1.4), 2> and the second sample is <11, 12, 13, 14, (0.5, 0.1, 00, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0), 12> with different lengths of just that one entry (here, index 4) per sample (and ultimately with each of those entries being 3 different numbers), but I'm trying to get anything working that isn't just a list of numbers.

Edit: If there is a better way to do this, like a different thing in tensorflow, a particular function in Matlab that can deal with the multiple-tuple entry that I want in my samples, please suggest it!

So this works:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

trainX = np.array([
            [19, 1] ,
            [10, 3] ,
            [0, 0] ,
            [11, 14] ,
            ])
print(trainX)
print(trainX.shape)

trainY = np.array([ 1, 1, 0, 1 ])
print(trainY)
print(trainY.shape)

feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=2)]
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                            n_classes=3, 
                                            hidden_units=[10])

classifier.fit(x=trainX, y=trainY, steps=2000)

print("Done.")
exit()
```

And changing trainX to this works,

```
trainX = np.array([
            [19, (1)] ,
            [10, (3)] ,
            [0, (0)] ,
            [11, (14)] ,
            ])
```

But this:

```
trainX = np.array([
            [19, (1, 1)] ,
            [10, (3, 9)] ,
            [0, (0, 0)] ,
            [11, (14, 6)] ,
            ])
```

fails due to a numpy error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./supersimple.py", line 8, in <module>
    [11, (14, 6)] ,
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

So if you change the np.array type to an object by adding 'dtype = np.object' at the end of the array or just move the tuple to the front (I believe this allows numpy to decide immediately that this is an object type) like this:

```
trainX = np.array([
            [(1, 1), 19] ,
            [(3, 9), 10] ,
            [(0, 0), 0] ,
            [(14, 6), 11] ,
            ])
```

it fails in tensorflow instead:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InternalError: Unable to get element from the feed as bytes.
```

The total output / stack trace is here:

```
$ python3 ./supersimple.py 

[[(1, 1) 19]
[(3, 9) 10]
[(0, 0) 0]
[(14, 6) 11]]
(4, 2)
[1 1 0 1]
(4,)
WARNING:tensorflow:Change warning: default value of `enable_centered_bias` will change after 2016-10-09. It will be disabled by default.Instructions for keeping existing behaviour:
Explicitly set `enable_centered_bias` to 'True' if you want to keep existing behaviour.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using default config.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 972, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 954, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors.py", line 463, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InternalError: Unable to get element from the feed as bytes.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./supersimple.py", line 22, in <module>
    classifier.fit(x=trainX, y=trainY, steps=2000)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py", line 435, in fit
    max_steps=max_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 333, in fit
    max_steps=max_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 708, in _train_model
    max_steps=max_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/graph_actions.py", line 285, in _monitored_train
    None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitored_session.py", line 368, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitored_session.py", line 521, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitored_session.py", line 488, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitored_session.py", line 619, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitored_session.py", line 488, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 717, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 915, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 985, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InternalError: Unable to get element from the feed as bytes.
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to treat the dynamic length tuple as a sparse tensor (with length = max length of the dynamic tuple, if that is feasible).

Then convert to embedding/one hot so that it's a dense tensor, since DNNClassifier requires input as dense tensor.

Comment: I tried converting the np.array to a tensor and feeding that into the classifier but DNNClassifier explicitly wouldn't accept a tensor.  I can certainly determine a max length of any of the set of tuples (there's only 30 samples so I can just look).  But you're saying I can stuff a tensor into the numpy array? and then convert the entire array of samples into a dense tensor? I've read about the one hot vectors in the MNIST examples but I will have actual values in most of the tuples of the dynamic entry, not just a single non-zero marker.

Comment: E.g. one of my sample's dynamic sized vector is 92 floats and none of them are 0's.  None of the data is very sparse :|

Comment: In you case, you might benefit from simply just creating a real_valued_column of dimension 'max_size', and just use numpy to .pad() each of the dynamic list entry to max_size before you call .fit().

Comment: (The sparse tensor route is probably not worth it given the simplicity of your dataset)

Comment: So I guess you mean something like this?  (doesn't work; on the right track?) trainX = np.array([[19] ,[10],[0],[11]])
# dynamic tuples
tuplesX = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 3, 3],[3, 9, 1, 1, 1],[0, 0, -1, -1, -1],[14, 6, 3, 4, -1]])
trainY = np.array([1,1,0,1])
simplevalues = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=1)]
dynamictuples = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension = 5)] classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=[simplevalues, dynamictuples],          n_classes=3,hidden_units=[10])
classifier.fit(x=[trainX, tuplesX], y=trainY, steps=2000)

Comment: I'm pulling loosely from here https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/wide/index.html but it's not the DNNClassifier and they call the .fit() differently.

Comment: Yeah exactly.  Basically pad the tuples to 0 if it has a shorter length than max_size.  I would have expected all your zeros to be at the end though, ex. if you have [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5]], then after padding it should become [[1,2,3,0,0], [1,2,3,4,5]]

Comment: Okay, I'll keep trying to get this to work.  Unfortunately 0 is a valid value here; it won't happen in every sample, but when it does, it's (probably) really important.  The dynamic length entry is the recorded distance between objects of interest for a time, which is from 9 - 15 minutes depending on the sample, and to generate a tiny data set I've averaged every 20 seconds.  But I could add 100 or something so that the (valid) 0's have non-zero values instead and pad with 0s.

Comment: Or you could consider replicating the last element in the list, so that the distance remains the same for the rest of the time.  Not sure if that makes sense for your data.

Comment: I can't join the two matrices as input as my x value.  What should it actually be?  This is garbage: classifier.fit(x=[trainX, tuplesX], y=trainY, steps=2000).  But I don't know how to stitch them together since making a new numpy matrix out of the two of them is going to be the same problem I had originally.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for simple concat?  Ex. a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
b = np.array([[5, 6]])
d = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)
print d
[[1 2 3 4 5 6]]

Comment: If I understand what you originally suggested correctly, that would mean I suddenly have several thousand features (when I scale up to the actual data), instead of 11 features (where one of the features is a bunch of tuples).

Comment: Sorry -- the 11 feature stuff is in regards to my real data.   In my toy sample data in the question that makes it have 3 features instead of 2 features (where one feature is 2 numbers each).

Comment: Not sure if I understand your setup, but I think I got the gist.  If scale is a concern, you will have to go with my original proposal - i.e. I would try either 1.) Pad the data with zeroes (or the last element value as previously discussed) and read in as real_valued_column, or 2.) Scale the input so that it becomes integer (ex. 1.7 -> 17), then read in as sparse_column_with_integerized_feature().  In both cases you will then convert to embedding_column() to lower the final dimensionality.  

My hunch tells me that you can't avoid some preprocessing.